# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: node.js, authentication, postman, node-modules

**user schema(user.js)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : {type :String , required:true ,unique:true},
    email :{type : String , required:true , unique:true},
    password:{type:String , required:true} ,
    isAdmin :{
      type : Boolean,
      default:false,
    },  
  },
 {timestamps:true}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('userData' , userSchema);
```

**auth.js** (where I tries to implement authentication)

```
     const User = require("../Database/User");  //importing user schema

     const router = require('express').Router();

     // Register

     router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
       const newUser = new User({
         username: req.body.username,
         email: req.body.email,
         password: req.body.password,
       });


       try {
         const saveUser = await newUser.save();
         res.status(201).json(saveUser);
       } catch (err) {
         res.status(500).json(err);
       }
     });

     module.exports = router;
```

**index.js** (entry point)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth'); // authentication 

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.Mongoose_url)
  .then(() => console.log("connection to database is  successful"))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.use('/api/user' , userRoute);
app.use('/api/auth' , authRoute);


app.listen(2000, () => {
  console.log("server is running on port ");
});
```

now when i tries to post data using postman it shows as below :
server is running on port
connection to database is successful
**(node:4320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
at E:\GillyWeedBackend\routes\auth.js:9:24
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
at next (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (E:\GillyWeedBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)**

why it is throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add `app.use(express.json());` in the main file(entry point)  as we are getting data in JSON format so it is necessary to add it.